# How to update google chrome portable

Tags: google-chrome, updates

I use Google chrome portable (so I can transfer cookies between PC's using my USB drive) and I'm getting notifications saying I need to update chrome, but doesn't give an option for chrome portable, how am I supposed to update Google chrome portable? i tried googling it, but it only gives results for either hacking in a update or stuff for the non-portable version.

Comment: When a new version of Chrome is released, which happens every 6 weeks, manually download and "install" the updated copy of Chrome portable.  Of course the portable version of Google Chrome, can and will update, unless its being blocked from doing so because of a network policy.

Comment: If you use a portable apps manager, for example liberkey, then updates will be offered to you ...

Answer (score 4):

I've been using PortableApps Chrome Portable since it's been available.

Here's how I update it:

1. Download the .paf.exe from https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable

   Run it and provide the location of Chrome Portable's existing directory (e.g. P:\GoogleChromePortable

   That's it, the installer automatically downloads and updates everything over existing installation while retaining all settings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome cant be never true portable because security reasons... so if not installed properly always shows error in update/check menu. Only thing I found (after cca 5 seconds of Googling is this [chrome-portable-updater-for-windows](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/03/13/chrome-portable-updater-for-windows/) ... tested and working (with some Defender exceptions) automatically downloads last version of Chrome and replace old one in Chrome folder

Second way is using portable chromium based browser with google sync features.

Answer (score -3):

Downolad the new version of chrome (.zip or .paf, as called by portableapps) then extract it.
Once you've done, enter in the folder created, then in the "Apps" subfolder, copy the one called with the name of version (es. Chrome56.0.234.34).
Then paste it (replace it) in the same path of old version.
So you can change the "core" without touch the folders called Profile, Plugins or Extensions.

Comment: Your instructions are clearly for the PortableApps.com platform but it is the worst possible way. The installer itself does a far better job of updating the portable app; why extract and manual labor?